# prove Cartesian product of countable non empty sets is not empty without Zorn's Lemma

Tags: general-topology

I saw this question in the book A Taste of Topology by Volker Runde:

Let $(S_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ be a sequence of nonempty sets. Show without invoking Zorn's lemma that $\prod^{\infty}_{n=1}S_n$ is not empty.

I'm puzzled as to how this can be done without Zorn's Lemma/Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Well, this is **equivalent** to the countable axiom of choice.

Comment: The statement seems to be the exact formulation of the axiom of countable choice. It is strictly weaker then usual axiom of choice, but is conceptually the same.

Comment: There is quite a conceptual difference between the countable axiom of choice and the real unrestricted axiom of choice. For example, the Hahn-Banach theorem on a separable Banach space may be proved  using induction only. So I suppose Runde wants to emphasize the difference?

Comment: The axiom of countable choice is not provable from the other axioms of set theory, unless the other axioms are already an inconsistent system.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have shown, the statement is equivalent to the axiom of countable choice which is independent from ZF (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory).

However, frequently the axiom of countable choice is confused with the principle of mathematical induction. I do not claim that Runde does it, but it is not impossible.

You will find many proofs in the literature where something is "constructed inductively". An example is the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem (every bounded sequence of real numbers has a convergent subsequence). Here one makes infinitely many choices to obtain the desired subsequence, but usually this is not acknowledged as the use of the axiom of choice (in this case more precisely the *axiom of dependent choice*).

If you are interested in that subject see for instance

http://emis.ams.org/journals/CMUC/pdf/cmuc9703/herrli.pdf

http://www.mat.uc.pt/~ggutc/teses/teseingles.pdf

https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/105069/CommentatMathUnivCarol_007-1966-3_11.pdf

Keremedis, Kyriakos. "Disasters in topology without the axiom of choice." Archive for Mathematical Logic 40.8 (2001): 569-580