# Show that $\{ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} u_n b_n \textrm{ | } (b_n) \in \{ 0, 1 \}^\mathbb{N} \}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

**The problem**

Consider a real sequence $(u_n)$ with non-negative terms. We assume that $\sum u_n$ converges.

I would like to show that $\{ \sum_{n = 0}^{+ \infty} u_n b_n \textrm{ | } (b_n) \in \{ 0, 1 \}^\mathbb{N} \}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

**What I have tried**

I have tried to use the sequential characterisation of closed sets: let $(b^k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of *elements of $\{ 0, 1 \}^\mathbb{N}$* and assume  $\sum_{n = 0}^{+ \infty} u_n b_n^k \to x \in \mathbb{R}$ when $k \to +\infty$. The goal is to show there exists $(c_n) \in \{ 0, 1 \}^\mathbb{N}$ such that $x = \sum_{n = 0}^{+ \infty} u_n c_n$.

I also assumed in the first instance that the $u_n$ are positive.

But I do not know how to expose such a sequence $(c_n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(b^k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, such that there exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}u_nb_n^k \rightarrow x \text{ when } k \rightarrow +\infty$.

Let's study the sequence $(b_0^k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$. It is bounded so we can find an increasing function $\varphi_0 : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ such that $(b_0^{\varphi_0(k)})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to a value $c_0 \in \{0,1\}$, according to Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.

Now, study $(b_1^{\varphi_0(k)})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$. Again, you can find $\varphi_1 : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ increasing such that $(b_1^{\varphi_0(\varphi_1(k))})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to a value $c_1 \in \{0,1\}$.

And so on, assuming $\varphi_0, ..., \varphi_{n-1}$ are built for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we build $\varphi_{n}$ increasing such that $(b_n^{(\varphi_0 \circ \cdots \circ \varphi_{n})(k))})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges towards $c_n \in \{0,1\}$ (actually, it is stationary to it).

We finally set $\phi(n) = (\varphi_0 \circ \cdots \circ \varphi_{n})(n)$ for all $n$. $\phi$ is an increasing function. So, the limit of $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}u_nb_n^{\phi(k)}$ when $k \to +\infty$ is still $x$.

But we can show that the limit is also $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}u_nc_n$. Indeed, let $\epsilon > 0$. There exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n = N+1}^{+\infty}u_n \leq \epsilon$. As $b_0^{\phi(k)}, ..., b_N^{\phi(k)}$ tend towards $c_0, ..., c_N$ when $k \to +\infty$, there exists $K$ such that for $k \geq K$, these quantities are equal to their limits (because they alternate between discrete values).

So, we have, for all $k \geq K$:

$$
\begin{align*}
\left| \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}u_n b_n^{\phi(k)} - \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}u_n c_n \right| 
&= \left| \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}u_n \left( b_n^{\phi(k)} -c_n \right) \right| \\
&= \left| \sum_{n = N+1}^{+\infty}u_n \left( b_n^{\phi(k)} -c_n \right) \right| \\
&\leq \sum_{n = N+1}^{+\infty}u_n \left| b_n^{\phi(k)} -c_n \right| \\
&\leq \sum_{n = N+1}^{+\infty}u_n \leq \epsilon \\
\end{align*}
$$

because $\left| b_n^{\phi(k)} -c_n \right| \leq 1$ as $b_n^{\phi(k)}, c_n \in \{ 0, 1 \}$.

To conclude, as the limit is unique, $x = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}u_n c_n$ and the set is closed.

**$\phi$ is well-defined and increasing**

Let us call an increasing function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ an **extraction**. We will prove $\phi$ is one. Clearly, $\phi$ is well-defined. A property that can be easily showed by induction is that for all extraction $s$, $s(n) \geq n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Moreover, composing an arbitrary number of extractions still gives you an extraction.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We will show $\phi(n+1) > \phi(n)$.

$$
\begin{align*}
\phi(n+1) 
&= (\varphi_0 \circ \cdots \circ \varphi_{n+1})(n+1) & \\
&> (\varphi_0 \circ \cdots \circ \varphi_{n+1})(n) & \textrm{$\varphi_0 \circ \cdots \circ \varphi_{n+1}$ is increasing}\\
&= (\varphi_0 \circ \cdots \circ \varphi_{n})(\varphi_{n+1}(n)) \\
&\geq (\varphi_0 \circ \cdots \circ \varphi_{n})(n) = \phi(n) & \textrm{$\varphi_0 \circ \cdots \circ \varphi_{n}$ is increasing and $\varphi_{n+1}(n) \geq n$}\\
\end{align*}
$$

So at the end you have $\phi(n+1) > \phi(n)$: $\phi$ is an extraction.

**$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, b_n^{\phi(k)} \underset{k \to +\infty} {\longrightarrow} c_n$**

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Recall $\varphi_n$ has been constructed so that $b_n^{\varphi_0 \circ \cdots \circ \varphi_n(k)} \underset{k \to +\infty} {\longrightarrow} c_n$. Let $k \geq n$ and set $\psi(k) = (\varphi_{n+1} \circ \cdots \circ \varphi_k)(k)$. In the same manner as above, one can show that $\psi(\cdot + k)$ is an extraction and then $b_n^{\phi(k)} = b_n^{( \varphi_0 \circ \cdots \circ \varphi_n ) (\psi(k))} \underset{k \to +\infty} {\longrightarrow} c_n$.

Comment: The key is that $\{0,1\}$ is a compact discrete tological space (you regard it in the natural way as a subset of $\mathbb R$). You try to show that each sequence $(\xi_k)$ in $X = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \{0,1\}$ has a componentwise convergent subsequence, i.e. that $X$ is (sequentially) compact with respect to the product topology. This would be a special case of Tychonoff's theorem. But you have a gap: You construct subsequences $(\xi_{\Phi_n(k)})$, $\Phi_n =  \varphi_0 \circ \ldots \circ \varphi_n$, such that you have componentwise convergence for the first $n$ coordinates.

Comment: How can you be sure that you get some $\Phi_\infty$ with componentwise convergence for **all** coordinates? I.e. why is the "infinite" composition of the $\varphi_n$ well-defined and an increasing function on $\mathbb  N$? You can of course construct the $\Phi_n$ and the $c_n$ as you did without referring to a "limit" $\Phi_\infty$, but still you need a **single** subsequence of $(\xi_n)$ converging to $(c_n)$.

Comment: I will answer the last comment's questions in my answer. Thanks for asking such clarifications.

Comment: You will need the axiom of choice (this enters in any proof of Tychonoff's theorem). In fact you make infinitely many **choices** (the $\varphi_n $). Perhaps Zorn's lemma will be helpful.

Comment: I think I have not used the axiom of choice in my proof. Do you still think it is incorrect. I have added some clarifications.

Comment: Of course your $\phi$ is an extraction and this gives you a subsequence of $(b^k)$. I called this function $\Phi_n$ in my comments. It depends explicity on $n$. You will not have $\Phi_{n+1} = \Phi_n$. Thus $b_n^{\Phi_N(k)} \to c_n$ for $n \le N$, but there is no reason why  $b_{N+1}^{\Phi_N(k)} \to c_{N+1}$. That is why you need some $\Phi_\infty$.

Comment: I do not understand why you think $\phi$ is indexed by $n$. The $\varphi_n$ are. But not $\phi$. What do you precisely disagree with in the last clarification? Thank you again.

Comment: In fact I misunderstood your definition. But my main point is that you use the axiom of choice (which is absolutely okay in my eyes). You have a recursive construction of functions $\Phi_n = \varphi_0 \circ \ldots \circ \varphi_n$ and then want to define $\phi = \Phi_\infty$ by $\phi(n) = \Phi_n(n)$. In other words, you try to construct a function $\phi : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ inductively by starting with $\phi(0)$ and then by extending it stepwise, involving a choice, to $\phi(1), \ldots, \phi(n),\phi(n+1), \ldots$. But you never get a function defined on $\mathbb N$.

Comment: To obtain such a function, you must make *infinitely many choices*, and that is the axiom of choice (or more precisely a somewhat weaker version: The axiom of of dependent choice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice.) "Inductive constructions" as yours are frequently misunderstood to produce an **infinite** sequence of numbers or other objects. Perhaps you think it is nitpicking, but is is not. If you are interested, look at Herrlich, Horst. "Choice principles in elementary topology and analysis." Commentationes Mathematicae Universitatis Carolinae 38.3 (1997): 545-552.

Comment: I see. In fact, I do not know deeply the theory behind my way of choosing the $\varphi_n$. I do it naturally as I have seen others doing so. Thanks for precising me this.
But, by the end of the day, my solution is valid, isn't it?

Comment: Everything is okay in your proof. Everybody would accept it as correct. Just be aware that you need more than mathematical induction: You invoke the axiom of choice, although it is not clearly visible. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1996219. To understand the difference:  You can use induction to prove that a property $P(n)$ which is **given** for all $n$ is true for all $n$, but you cannot use it to **construct** a sequence of objects by recursive choices. The latter is the axiom of of dependent choice. But that goes to the foundations of set theory, and only few people care about.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(b^k)$ be a sequence in $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, such that there exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}u_nb_n^k \rightarrow x \text{ for } k \rightarrow \infty$

Notice first that for any  $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b_1^k,...,b_N^k$ are constant for each $k > N$ (this is because $u_n \ge 0)$. Therefore we can construct a $b \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ corresponding to such constants.

Now all you need to prove is that $x = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}u_nb_n$, which should be relatively simple. For example, show that the differences of the partial sums converge to 0 by the tail lemma.

Comment: So you are saying, for $N$ fixed, that the sequence $(b_N^k)$ is stationary. But I still do not understand why. Could you explain why?

Comment: Nono, I'm saying for a fixed $N$, the sequence will evetually be stationary in the first $N$ entries. We can prove this by contradiction.

Assume that for some $N$, $b_N^k$ changes between $0$ and $1$ infinitely often. Then the sequence of infinite sums $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}u_nb_n^k$ will not convergerge for $k \rightarrow \infty$, since the $u_Nb_N^k$ term will keep on switching between $0$ and $u_N$.

Comment: Here is a simple counter-example: it is possible that $(b_0^{2p}, b_1^{2p}) = (0, 1)$ and $(b_0^{2p+1}, b_1^{2p+1}) = (1, 0)$, and $u_0 = u_1$. So, the value of the first two terms is not stationary. But I think it works using  well-chosen subsequences. @Richard Jensen

Comment: Really good point! However, it is fixable. As you notice, this can only happen for $i,j$ where $u_i = u_j$. A set $\{ i_1, i_2... \}$  where $u_{i_1} = u_{i_2} = ... $ is finite. For let $u_i \ge 0$. Let $0<\epsilon < u_{i_1}$. Pick $N>0$ such that $|\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} u_nb_n^k - x|<\epsilon$ for all $k>N$. The finite set will then for $k>N$ have the same number of 1 and 0 coefficients, so for a candidate $b$, we can just pick the relevant entries to have those number of $1$'s and $0$'s.

For example, say $u_1 = u_2 = 1$, for $k>N$ exactly on of $b_1^k$, $b_2^k$ is 0, $b_1 = 1$ $b_2=0$