# Show $b \in \{ 0, 1 \}^{\mathbb{N}} \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}u_n b_n$ is continuous

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, continuity

**The problem**

Let $\sum u_n$ be a convergent series with non-negative terms.

For $b, b' \in \{ 0, 1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$, we define $\textrm{d}(b, b') := \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{|b_n - b'_n|}{2^n}$. One can show $\textrm{d}$ is a metric on $\{ 0, 1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

I would like to show the function $f : b \in \{ 0, 1 \}^{\mathbb{N}} \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}u_n b_n$ is continuous with respect to $\textrm{d}$ and the usual distance on $\mathbb{R}$.

We can use the fact $\{ \sum_{n = 0}^{+ \infty} u_n b_n \textrm{ | } (b_n) \in \{ 0, 1 \}^\mathbb{N} \}$ is a closed set (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3470871/show-that-sum-n-in-mathbbn-u-n-b-n-textrm-b-n-in-0-1) for the proof).

**My try**

I have tried to use the sequential characterisation for continuity. Let $c \in \{ 0, 1 \}^\mathbb{N}$ and $(b^k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \in \left( \{ 0, 1 \}^\mathbb{N} \right)^\mathbb{N}$ such that $\textrm{d}(b^k, c) \underset{k \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$. We want to show that $f(b^k) \underset{k \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} f(c)$.

$\left( f(b^k) \right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded. I would like to show it has a unique accumulation point.

As the aforementioned set is closed, any accumulation point of the latter sequence is in this set.

But I do not know how to show neither the accumulation point is unique nor is is $f(c)$. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $d(b,b') <\frac 1 {2^{N}}$ then we must have $b_1=b_1',b_2=b_2',...,b_{N-1}=b_{N-1}'$. [Because $b_i \neq b_i'$ implies $|b_i-b_i'|=1$ and $d(b,b') \geq \frac 1  {2^{i}}$].

So we get $|\sum_i u_ib_i-u_ib_i'| =\sum\limits_{i=N+1}^{\infty} u_n$. Can you finish the proof?

Comment: Yes I know how to finish the proof from there. But I would like to focus on the accumulation points point of view. Thanks @Kabo Murphy